# Add in app purchases once the app is approved

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I would like to know if Apple allows me to add new in-app purchases products once the app is approved and in that case, are they going to re-evaluate the app or only the product?
(the binary do not need to be changed as the product name will be dynamically generated).

Could I generate at the same time multiple products (very similar in their description) one for each month of the year?

Thanks,

McMc

Comment: If the answer @tia supplied was helpful to you, would you kindly check the checkmark under the voting arrows on that answer? It helps all of us know your question has already been answered, and gives tia some points for taking the time to help out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Apple will allow you to add in-app purchase without resubmitting the app. However, your new in-app purchase product must be testable for them, e.g. listed in your app. If the review person cannot test it, he/she will not approve it and will ask you how to test it.

You can generate one products for each month, as long as they are not actually the same product.